# Change ion-tabs height on ionic

Tags: html, tabs, ionic-framework, height

i'm trying to change the ion-tabs height. I went in _variables.scss and change the tabs-height:

```
$tabs-height:                     200px !default;
```

but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
    <ion-tab title="Clienti" icon-on="ion-ios-body" icon-off="ion-ios-body-outline">
        <ion-view id="clienti" class="tabView">

        </ion-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Dati" icon-on="ion-ios-briefcase" icon-off="ion-ios-briefcase-outline">
        <ion-content class="tabView" has-bouncing="false">
            <div class="ca"></div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you can do it with css. then i did this.

```
<ion-tab title="Clienti" icon-on="ion-ios-body" icon-off="ion-ios-body-outline" class="top-44">
      <ion-view id="clienti" class="tabView">

      </ion-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Dati" icon-on="ion-ios-briefcase" icon-off="ion-ios-briefcase-outline">
      <ion-content class="tabView" has-bouncing="false">
            <div class="ca"></div>
      </ion-content>
</ion-tab>
```

css

```
.top-44  .tab-nav{
  height: 54px;
  top:54px !important;
 }
```